# HAProxy served 503s and I don't know why

Tags: haproxy, 503-error

Yesterday, for around 10 minutes, my haproxy served a lot of 503 pages (directly from `errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http`) and I don't know why. I have no health checks to my backends, so for sure these were not marked as disabled. The stats page doesn't show that a limit was reached (in the marked red areas).

[image: haproxy stats page]

```
global
    maxconn 20000
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    daemon
    ...

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    timeout http-request 30s
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 120s
    timeout client 30s
    ...

frontend frontend_for_all_sites
    maxconn 20000
    mode http
    bind *:80

    option http-buffer-request
    timeout http-request 30s

    ...

    use_backend www_backend      if acl_hostname_www
    use_backend static_backend   if acl_hostname_static

backend www_backend
    option forwardfor
    server www localhost:9090 maxconn 5000

backend static_backend
    option forwardfor
    server s localhost:9090 maxconn 5000
```

Where should I look at next to figure out why did that happen?

Comment: Are you sure localhost:9090 was actually accepting any connections?

Comment: @kubanczyk I can't really tell. I did a local test, and if it was out of connections or too slow, haproxy would throw a 504 based on the configured timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the backend, and I managed to point out what was happening after adding a `%ts` (termination_state) in the `log-format` so I could validate that indeed the backend was unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `default_backend` ?

If

```
use_backend www_backend      if acl_hostname_www
use_backend static_backend   if acl_hostname_static
```

fails, there is not default backend, hence `503`